# Twitter bootstrap move checkbox to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

Trying to make my checkbox show in a order with 5 in each columns with two columns. I am very unsure how to do it with the checkboxes and position the input forms to the left.

Here is the bootply:

http://www.bootply.com/128081

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your check boxes are in their own `<div class="row">`. You need to put all the columns in one row. Also, your columns are col-md-6. Twitter bootstrap's largest column default width is col-md-12, so you'll wanna make the sections col-md-(12/number of columns) if you want the check boxes to fit in the row.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As dardrone said - you would need to put them in a **row**, and then split that into 2 columns. Something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        show the first column of checkboxes here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        show the second column of checkboxes here
    </div>
</div>
```